# Project Manager always disturbs me when I'm busy doing something

Tags: work-environment, personal-problems

I'm a web developer and recently I get upset and my head hurts every time our project manager PM's me through our slack channel and will ask me to prioritize a task first. I can do urgent revisions. It's okay once in a while (like 3 to 5 times a week) but every 3 to 4 hours????. It's like you're focused on solving a Rubik's cube and then you will be ask to solve another. I don't know what to do.

Any tips?

Comment: Is he your boss? When you get assigned a task, what does he say about the deadline? Are those small tasks (3.. 4 hours tasks)?

Comment: She's the boss' assistant. She's also the PM.. Revision tasks that are good for an hour or two..

Comment: Have you talked with her about how to use your time efficiently?

Comment: I think that's the problem with me. I'm not good at having conversation with people when it comes to this kind of matter. It might get things worse.

Comment: So if "_Revision tasks that are good for an hour or two_", why it is a problem that she comes every 3.. 4 hours? Did you mean that you have to do other tasks assigned to you by your direct manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the bread and butter of "hot" maintenance programming. I did it for several years, and actually did like it. It's not for everyone, though. You have to like gunpowder smell.

The question is, what is the business drive behind your activity? reducing your productivity for gaining in delay is a trade-off. If the business behind is actually to develop quick evolutions in emergency, and this kind of interruption is actually what gives value to your work, then get used to it. Or look for a bigger project.

OTOH, if the business added value of delivering your work a few hours earlier is limited, then you have a management problem. As it seems to be the boss assistant, and not the boss itself, the person asking you this kind of things might be not aware of the interruption costs in programmimng.[Here is a link you can use to explain](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/02/12/human-task-switches-considered-harmful/). You will have also to negotiate small waiting times(i.e. you need 45 minutes to finish your current task, and then you'll do the next urgent things). It can be awkward to ask, but worthwhile(if the emergency is not a business driver, of course, in which case you've got nothing to negotiate).